# How to make Eclipse's "find text in working set" command use a default working set?

Tags: eclipse

As a user new to Eclipse, I am trying to use the `Find Text in Working Set` command to mimic Visual Studio's `Find in Files` command. It works fine, except that every time I have to tell it which working set to use. And I only have one working set!

How can I get this command to remember the working set from one invocation to the next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `File Search` command does what I need: it can search all the files (or a subset), and it remembers my working set.

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong, short-cut is **"CTRL+SHIFT+R"**

Comment: That's `Open Resource` for me.